# Screen resolution issue

Tags: vb.net

I have written an application.  It works fine on some resolutions but most of the controls are over lapped when it is run on some other computers.
Is there any way of setting the application automatically when it is run on different computers?

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Setting the application to do what automatically? What are you using WinForms/WPF/Silverlight/WebForms?

Comment: Did you write the application with a given minimum acceptable resolution?  Sounds like no.

Comment: Remember, not all displays will support a higher resolution.  If someone on a netbook that only goes to 1200x600 runs your app, it's your job to make sure your app will work at that size. It is not your job to try to resize the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229649.aspx
(assuming this is not WPF)

You can do a lot with docking and anchoring to help your form maintain it's usability at different sizes.  But, there are practical limits.  You can enforce a minimum size and ensure that your controls resize appropriately down to that limit.